Prove that if $Bx=0$ holds for all $x$ then $B$ must be the zero matrix.
It seems like an obvious fact. Say we have $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ and for every such $x$,
$$Bx = 0$$
The only way to satisfy this is if $B$ is the zero matrix and conversely, if $x$ is from some smaller sub-space, then a non-zero $B$ matrix must exist.
Is this statement correct for both square and rectangular $B$ matrices? And for either of the cases, how would one go about proving it?

Choose a basis.

You can also show that $B$ is the additive identity in the Abelian group of $m\times n$ matrices.

Isn't that implicit in $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$?

a basis is never implicit imo; it does not come for free from the axioms of a vector space.

i mean this is pretty obvious, right?? like when we proceed in eigenvalues we have $(A-\lambda I)X=0$....so as $X$ is non zero we must have $A-\lambda I=0$ or $\textrm{det}(A-\lambda I)=0$

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous not sure what you mean by this, but $(A-\lambda I)X=0$ only holds for eigenvectors of $A$, and implies $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ because $A-\lambda I$ is never invertible.

@Chris can't we just say that $B=A-\lambda I$ and $x=X$ i.e. eigenvector of A? as eigenvector is also a column matrix so ig we can say that

If $e_i^TBe_j \ne 0$ then $Be_i \ne 0$. Hence if $Bx = 0$ for all $x$ you must have  $e_i^TBe_j  = [B]_{ij} = 0$ for all $i,j$ hence the matrix $B=0$.

Let $B$ be a matrix $\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$, then in any basis $\{e_1,\dots , e_n\}$ for $\mathbb R^n$ and any basis $\{f_1,\dots, f_m\}$ for $\mathbb R^m$, $B$ has coefficients $B_i^j$,
so:
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
B_1^1&\cdots &B_n^1\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
B_1^m&\cdots&B_n^m
\end{pmatrix}$$
then:
$$Be_i=\sum_{j=1}^mB_i^jf_j=0$$
But $\{f_j\}$ is a basis, so the $B_i^j$ have to be zero hence $B$ is the zero matrix.

I'm not familiar with the $B_i^j$ notation. What does it signify?

Oh my bad, let me include the summation.

@RohitPandey did my edit clear this up?\

@RohitPandey $B_i^j$ is the element in the $i^{th}$ column and in the $j^{th}$ row. You might have came across it in two-index form $B_{ij}$ which means the exact same thing.

And what about the converse? If $x$ is from a sub-space then a non-zero $B$ matrix must exist? Or is that not correct?

I’m not sure what you mean by this, every $x$ spans a one dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, but a non zero matrix $B$ must exist that does what?

Choose $n$ basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^n:e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ where each $e_i=(0,\dots,1,\dots,0)$ with 1 in the $i^{th}$ position.
$$\forall e_i,Be_i=0$$
Because every column of B is the zero vector, B has to be the zero matrix

Thanks, this did help a lot in making it "snap".
